# Net Beans Crashes

Tags: java, netbeans, graphic

I am new to such kind of problem. My Net Beans IDE Crashes because of my graphic card! I have AMD Radeon R9 M200X Series Graphic Card with 2GB Memory Installed on my Machine. Whenever I try to create a new JFrame in Net Beans IDE; it suddenly crashes forcefully. I also have Intel HD Graphic Card (that may be by default/built in card)! I have come to know of this problem by uninstalling the AMD Graphic Card Drivers and Used my Net Beans IDE on INTEL GRAPHIC CARD!
The problem is strange that the IDE can't be used while I have ADM Radeon!
The error log file is as follow:

---

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=6496, tid=6980

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x0000000000000000

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000166e9800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=6980, stack(0x000000001ade0000,0x000000001afe0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x000000001afdd2f4, RBX=0x000007fefed60000, RCX=0x000000001afdd2f0, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000001afdd2a8, RBP=0x000000001afdd3b0, RSI=0x000007fef479fa00, RDI=0x000000001afdd920
R8 =0x0000000000000140, R9 =0x0000000000000006, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000001afdd2f4
R12=0x000000001afddb90, R13=0x000007fefb7953cc, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00000000166e9800
RIP=0x0000000000000000, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010213

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001afdd2a8)
0x000000001afdd2a8:   000007fefb793f5d 0072007400730069
0x000000001afdd2b8:   0061004d005c0079 006e006900680063
0x000000001afdd2c8:   00790053005c0065 006d006500740073
0x000000001afdd2d8:   007200750043005c 0074006e00650072
0x000000001afdd2e8:   0074006e006f0043 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd2f8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd308:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd318:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd328:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd338:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd348:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd358:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd368:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd378:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd388:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001afdd398:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000000000000)
0xffffffffffffffe0:   


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000001afdd2f4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000166e9800
RBX=0x000007fefed60000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000001afdd2f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000166e9800
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001afdd2a8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000166e9800
RBP=0x000000001afdd3b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000166e9800
RSI=0x000007fef479fa00 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000001afdd920 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000166e9800
R8 =0x0000000000000140 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000001afdd2f4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000166e9800
R12=0x000000001afddb90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000166e9800
R13=0x000007fefb7953cc is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x00000000166e9800 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000001ade0000,0x000000001afe0000],  sp=0x000000001afdd2a8,  free space=2036k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.getMaxConfigsImpl(I)I+0
j  sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.getMaxConfigs(I)I+10
j  sun.awt.Win32GraphicsDevice.getConfigurations()[Ljava/awt/GraphicsConfiguration;+69
j  javax.swing.ToolTipManager.getDrawingGC(Ljava/awt/Point;)Ljava/awt/GraphicsConfiguration;+36
j  javax.swing.ToolTipManager.showTipWindow()V+115
j  javax.swing.ToolTipManager$insideTimerAction.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+113
J 10142 C1 javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V (46 bytes) @ 0x000000000423345c [0x0000000004233120+0x33c]
J 14878 C1 javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run()V (95 bytes) @ 0x0000000004faa514 [0x0000000004fa9940+0xbd4]
J 15500 C2 java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x00000000044152e0 [0x0000000004414fe0+0x300]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1147  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000002906c26 [0x0000000002906bc0+0x66]
J 15438 C2 org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V (43 bytes) @ 0x00000000045e7e60 [0x00000000045e79c0+0x4a0]
J 20389 C2 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V (295 bytes) @ 0x00000000060a3ccc [0x00000000060a3840+0x48c]
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

---

I just need to know that is it possible for me to use NetBeans on Intel Hd Graphic Card instead of AMD Graphic Card because recently AMD had remove the option for switchable graphics! and now that the users of AMD have Crimson Software (whatever I am not intended for Graphics)!

Can somebody give me any Idea what's the resolution for this!
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Its only happening with the NetBeans IDE and AWT-Component Classes have not been working properly!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reason

**It was simple the IDE was crashing because of the AMD Radeon Crimson Edition Drivers for the Graphic Card!**

### Reference Link

### [Read Here the Official Netbeans IDE - README](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/35/1/README.html#KnownProblems)

### The Work Around

Just locate your **Netbeans.conf** file under the **root directory of your IDE** installation then open **etc folder** and **edit Netbeans.conf**.

In the edit mode locate for the string:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

In the above mentioned code just change the option as:

```
-J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=false
```

so that the new string would be:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=false -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

---

### What it does?

It is for the users of the machines that have dual graphic cards such as in my case I have an Intel HD Graphics 4400 Card and an AMD Radeon R9 M200X Series!

But the problem is that the AMD had just remove the switchable graphics so, you cant allow any windows app to forcefully use your Intel Graphics (May be I didn't find any way to do so!).

---

### Intended Audience

***This solution is for the users with machines having AMD Radeon Graphic Card and their Netbeans IDE forcefully Crashes because of AWT-Components Library!***

---

Thanks All!

Comment: I've been looking for a problem on the JVM or memory consumption the whole day. Thank you for the solution and it's details :) .